# How to store id as string in mongo db

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot

I am new to mongo DB. I have three attributes in my object as below:

```
{
"id":"id"
"name":"Name field",
"description":"Description field"
}
```

If I pass Id as string from spring boot application. Then it's getting stored as object. Is it possible to store id as what customer wants?
Below is my object class:

```
@Document
public class Topic {

@Id
private String id;
private String name;
private String description;

public Topic() {

}
public Topic(String id, String name, String description) {
    this.id= id;
    this.name = name;
    this.description = description;
}
public String getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
public String getDescription() {
    return description;
}
public void setDescription(String description) {
    this.description = description;
}
```

}

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.conventions.id-field